# Hadoop TestDFSIO program not able to complete reduce tasks properly in redhat linux

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running a hadoop TestDFSIO write program in hadoop configured on two redhat 6.4 linux systems but the program hangs after

> 100% map 16% reduce

I ran the TestDFSIO write workload as

```
hadoop jar hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar -write -nrFiles 960 -fileSize 1024 .
```

after formatting the namenode it worked fine for one run but again on second run it failed like that by hanging on after completing map tasks.

> 100% map 16% reduce.

After formatting the namenode it is able to complete one run of writing the data by

```
hadoop jar hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar -write -nrFiles 960 -fileSize 1024
```

but when I ran the read workload

```
hadoop jar hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar -read -nrFiles 960 -fileSize 1024
```

it stuck at the end stage after as:-

```
100% map 16% reduce done.
```

Why is the reduce task not able to finish properly ?

The logs of TaskTracker on master node shows (time and classname shortened) :-

`...0:15,541 INFO ....JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201309241959_0001_m_226512462 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
...0:15,814 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000958_0 0.0% reading test_io_8@790197504/1073741824 ::host = 9.122.227.170
...0:16,768 INFO ....TaskTracker: Received KillTaskAction for task: attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000957_1
...0:16,768 INFO ....TaskTracker: About to purge task: attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000957_1
...0:16,768 INFO ....IndexCache: Map ID attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000957_1 not found in cache
...0:17,559 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16597223% reduce > copy (478 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:18,355 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000958_0 1.0% finished test_io_8 ::host = 9.122.227.170
...0:18,355 INFO ....TaskTracker: Task attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000958_0 is done.
...0:18,355 INFO ....TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000958_0  was 93
...0:18,356 INFO ....TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
...0:18,498 INFO ....JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201309241959_0001_m_832308806 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
...0:20,584 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16597223% reduce > copy (478 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:21,697 INFO ....TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 9.122.227.170:50060, dest: 9.122.227.170:48771, bytes: 93, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID: attempt_201309241959_0001_m_000958_0, duration: 6041257
...0:26,608 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:32,632 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:35,655 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:41,679 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:47,700 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:50,721 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:56,744 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...0:59,766 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:05,789 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:11,812 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:14,835 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:20,859 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:26,885 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:29,908 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:35,931 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:41,955 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:44,978 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:51,002 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...1:57,025 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...2:00,048 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...2:06,072 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...2:12,096 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...2:15,119 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...2:21,143 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...2:27,167 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) > 
...2:30,190 INFO ....TaskTracker: attempt_201309241959_0001_r_000000_0 0.16631946% reduce > copy (479 of 960 at 0.00 MB/s) >`

[image: The Screenshot of the terminal where the hadoop process is stucked at the reduce jobs.]

The screen shot shows that the hadoop process is stuck in the reduce phase of the job.

Comment: Can you post logs from the jobtracker and the reduce job?

Comment: I have pasted the logs of the tasktracker. and the screenshot the terminal where it is hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue the problem was with the DNS Name resolution i had to edit the /etc/hosts file and remove the entry for localhost and add the actual hostname in them it certainly worked for me in Redhat Linux 6.4. for the hadoop cluster to identify with the hadoop master and hadoop slave.